# Multiple menu items highlighted in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, menu, navigation, categories

I've scoured the internet for several hours and turned up similar questions to mine, but they were all unanswered so I have come here for support.

I am using Wordpress as the CMS for my website. For my navigation menu, I am using wordpresses inbuilt navigation menu function. You add categories or page etc to this and it generates a list with certain classes you can style - like "current-menu-item".

My problem lies here: I have several categories in my menu, and some posts have to be assigned to multiple categories.

If a post was for example in a Category A only, then when you are on the page with that post, Category A would be highlighted in the menu.

If a post is in Category A and Category B, then when you are on the page with that post, Category A and Category B would both be highlighted.

What I want is for only one menu item to be highlighted, even though the post is in multiple categories.

Does anybody know how to do this? Much appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Perhaps you could style it using the `nth-of-type` CSS3 selector.

```
.current-menu-item:nth-of-type(1) {
    background:#ffff00;
    /* Highlight styles */
}
```

These styles would target only the first occurrence of the .current-menu-item. Likewise, you could choose to target the second with `nth-of-type(2)`, et cetera.

Comment: Great little hack.